# Hide header and/or footer when no scrollbar is present

Tags: jquery-mobile

In the jQuery Mobile documentation, I found the following code:

```
$("[data-position='fixed']").fixedtoolbar('show');
$("[data-position='fixed']").fixedtoolbar('hide');
$("[data-position='fixed']").fixedtoolbar('toggle')
```

The goal of this is to either hide or show the header and/or footer of a page.

After some testing and experimenting, I've found that this code only works when the content on your page is big enough to get a vertical scrollbar on the page.

For my project, I'll need to be able to hide and/or show the header and footer of pages that don't have a scrollbar (either because there is not enough content, or because of a custom scrollbar plugin).
Does anybody know how to achieve this, using a minimum of extra CSS/JavaScript? Thank you.

Comment: what about setting the min-height of your page content to the height of the window + height of footer and header ?

Answer (score 1):

```
     $("div:jqmData(role='footer')").show();
     $("div:jqmData(role='footer')").hide();
```

Or simply use the id of the footer and use .show() or .hide()

Hope it helped

Comment: +1 Very simple, clean and working solution. However when I hide the header, the space that it needed is still preserved, while I'd like the content to fill this space.

Comment: @Bram W. yes its seems to clip at the base , i tried other solutions but none seems to be working properly, But you can use .remove() to remove the html part all together. Here what you can do is get the html content of footer and store it in a variable , then write two functions for footerHide and footerShow , where in footerShow you can append the hmtl and do a trigger to updatelayout  And for footerHide use remove command to remove the footer html , This is not an apt solution as you will have to handle page refresh and other problems that may come up.